# how to return to a specific page after form submit based on value laravel

Tags: laravel, forms, return

i have a logic whereby on form submission i want to return to specific page based on a certain value the user choosed when submiting the form.the form works well but when i try to return it doesnt work.where might i be missing the point here.

```
 public function addtoorder(Request $request){
    $userid=Auth::user()->id;
     $addresses=Deliveryaddress::where('user_id',$userid)->first();
      if($request->isMethod('post')){
        $data=$request->all();
        $order = new Order();
        $order->name = Auth::user()->name;
        $order->phone =$addresses->phone;
        $order->county =$addresses->shipcharges->county;
        $order->town =$addresses->towns->town;
        $order->order_status="New Order";
        $order->payment_method = $request->payment_method;
        $order->user_id =$userid;
        $order->grand_total = Session::get('grand_total');
        $order->shipping_charges=$addresses->shipping_cost;
        $order->save();
        }
       if($data=="SKRILL"){
            return view('frontend.product.skrill');
        }elseif($data=="PAYPAL"){
            return view('frontend.product.paypal');
        }
     } 
  }
```

i have been able to save the data on the database but am unable to return to the specific pages.rather it return to blank page without any error,but it saves the data to the orders table perfectly.

Comment: Did you try debugging your own code? Like put `dd($data);` to try to see that is the value of `$data`.

Comment: What I see here in the code is you're assigning `$data=$request->all();` if the method is only post. Also `$request->all()` returns an array not a string.

Comment: @aceraven777 yes i tried it but didnt get anything.it just shows a blank page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess blank screen means that nothing was returned, because you are trying to check whether `$data`(which is array) is equal to some string.
My thoughts would be for you to try check string in your `if` statement.
Like this

```html
  if($data['payment_method'] === "SKRILL"){
            return view('frontend.product.skrill');
        }elseif(data['payment_method'] === "PAYPAL"){
            return view('frontend.product.paypal');
        }
```